# Cluster markers in MapBox, how to "accumulate" just distinct properties?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I want to show markers on a map, where each marker is a `UserLocation`. A `User` can have multiple `UserLocation`.
When I cluster markers, I'd like to show the list of the Users of those clustered markers, without duplicates.

For instance, let's take these 3 near markers:

```js
      { // Marker1
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {user_id : "Daniele"},
        geometry: { type        : 'Point',
                    coordinates : [lng0, lat0]
                  }
      },
      {// Marker2
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {user_id : "Daniele"},
        geometry: { type        : 'Point',
                    coordinates : [lng1, lat1]
                  }
      },
      {// Marker3
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {user_id : "Roberto"},
        geometry: { type        : 'Point',
                    coordinates : [lng2, lat2]
                  }
      }
```

When I cluster them, clicking the clustered circle, I want to see "Daniele, Roberto".
How can I do that?

Moreover, I'd like to set the size of circle, according to the distinct number of different users clustered (in the example above, should be 2).

---

**UPDATE 2

---

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/m36xfq0u/) <--

An idea could be build an array of distinct names, and then use the `length` expression to size the circle.

Anyway, there should be a kind of syntax error...

```js
 clusterProperties: {
  distinctNames : 
                ['case', 
                   /*cond  */ ["!", ['in',['get', 'user_id'], ['accumulated']]], 
                   /*result*/ ['concat', ['concat', ['get', 'user_id'], ',']],
                                                         
                   /*default*/ ['accumulated']
                ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-clusterProperties) you want to do something like this:

```
map.addSource(userData, {
   id: 'user-locations',
   type: 'geojson',
   data: 'myuserdata.geojson',
   cluster: true,
   clusterProperties: {
      names: ['concat', ['concat', ['get', 'user_id'], ',']]
   }
}
```

Clustered points in your source will now have a property, `names` which will contain the comma-separated (and comma-terminated) string of names.

> Moreover, I'd like to set the size of circle, according to the distinct number of different users clustered (in the example above, should be 2)

That sounds...challenging. One way I can think of doing that would be writing a custom accumulator function along these lines:

- Make the function return an array of two values, `[distinctNames, allNames]` where the first is an integer, and the second is a string.
- If `allNames` contains our current name, just return the array.
- Otherwise, return an array which is `[distinctNames + 1, allNames + thisName]`.

Manipulating arrays like this in Mapbox GL expressions is possible, but pretty fiddly. You need to use `['literal', ...]` and `['at', ...]`

The code would look something like this:

```js
   clusterProperties: {
      names: ['concat', ['concat', ['get', 'user_id'], ',']],
      distinctNames: [
          ['case', ['in', ['get', 'distinctNames'], ['at', ['accumulated'], 1]
            ['accumulated'],
            ['literal', ['+', ['at', ['accumulated'], 0], 1], ['concat', ['at', ['accumulated'], 1], ['get', 'distinctNames']]]
          ],
          ['concat', '%', ['get', 'user_id'], '%'] // wrap user ID in some unique character so we don't accidentally find user "rob" within another user "robin" for instance.
      ]
   }
```

It's unclear from the documentation exactly how the accumulator function works, or how you access the current value. Their example implies that it would be `['get', <name of cluster property>]` although that seems a bit weird.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I got your logic, I'll test it and let you know. thank you!

Comment: forget it... I don't know very well the expression syntax yet, and I'm a bit lost on the code. I think a parenthesis is missing... could you fix it please? It will help me to understand :)

Comment: I've updated my question, with a comment on your answer. I tried to follow your instruction but I am missing something..

Comment: update2 . trying to get 'accumulated' working

Comment: As I said, this is a pretty challenging task. I don't have an easy way to test this code, just hoping to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is not really clear, but here is how I achieved this "distinct accumulate".

From the [`clusterProperties`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-clusterProperties) definition:

*A custom reduce expression that references a special ["accumulated"] value, e.g.:*

```
{"sum": [["+", ["accumulated"], ["get", "sum"]], ["get", "scalerank"]]}
```

> Which results the same as: `{"sum": ["+", ["get", "scalerank"]]}`

In your case, you want to accumulate the `user_id` property from your markers without duplicates.

The logic is to add the `user_id` only if it has not already been added in the accumulated value.

```js
clusterProperties: {
  distinctUsers: [
    // ['accumulated'] is the current value iterated during the reduce (the property is defined at [1])
    // ['get', 'distinctCountries'] is the accumulated / concatenated string
    [
      // Concat accumulated value + current value if not present in accumulated
      'concat',
      ['get', 'distinctUsers'],
      [
        'case',
        ['in', ['accumulated'], ['get', 'distinctUsers']],  // If accumulated (user_id) has already been added
        '',  // Add EMPTY string
        ['concat', ', ', ['accumulated']],  // Add the user_id (concatenated with a comma in your case)
      ],
    ],
    ['get', 'user_id'], // [1]: source marker property iterated in the custom reduce function
  ]
}
```

As Steve said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66560685/12418748), you could also wrap the `user_id` in some unique character so you don't accidentally find user "rob" within another user "robin" for instance.

The source property `['get', 'user_id']` defined at `[1]` would become :

```js
['concat', '%', ['get', 'user_id'], '%']
```

Comment: Awesome! For a complete expressions beginner this is just pure gold <3